# What is the difference between 1206 and 0612 (reversed) SMD resistors?

Tags: pcb, resistors, resistance, surface-mount, circuit-design

I wanted to know what is the difference and if a 1206 resistor can be chosen as second source of a 0612 if the other specifications are the same

Comment: You could perhaps design a PCB to accept both formats, and then a 2nd source would work. Whether standard assembly programs would handle both, or you'd have to hand assemble, or have part-specific assembly programs, is another matter.

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned, 0612 resistors have the terminals on the long side of the body rather than on the short side. This is often done to minimize inductance which can interfere with high-speed circuits. It also improves current handling capabilities, and is often used in high current sense applications.

An 0612 cannot be replaced with a 1206.

##### 0612

[image: 0612 Package]

##### 1206

[image: 1206 Package]

Answer (score 13):

One has contacts on the narrow sides, one has contacts on the wide sides.

If you have a PCB already you can't fit the wrong component on the footprint as the pads are different.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is you get better heat conduction (more metal) in the 0612 and less parasitic inductance and resistance because you have more metal.